# Google Maps JavaScript API issue

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am following along google's official documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple.

I am attempting to set up the basic map following the above guide but the map is not rendering to the page. For clarification, the maps JavaScript API has been enabled through my google account and I've tested my API key which is for certain working. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Google map API</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>

</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<!-- async defer in first script tag if needed -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap" async defer ></script>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 10,
        });
        console.log("map", map);
    };
```

Here's a screenshot of the console output: https://postimg.cc/p5PsjqP1
There are NO errors showing up in the console but it is console logging the map variable. What am I missing here? Why isn't my basic map showing up?

Comment: try giving your div a height, like `<div id="map" style="height:500px"></div>` - see how the example page has a style tag, and a comment in that tag says **Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div**

Comment: There's an example built with jsfiddle on this page if you want an API key to work with/a working example. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Comment: Wow - the height styling is all it needed. Thank you Bravo!